# Permanent resident filing taxes from a UK employer

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, form-w-2

I am a US permanent resident with a UK employer. My employer tells me they do not issue W2 forms to staff outside UK. What do I do? Is there some other form I should be filling for my taxes?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a translation issue. W2s don't exist in the UK. Your likely after a [P60](https://www.gov.uk/payroll-annual-reporting/give-employees-p60-form). This is a detail of all the tax, NI, wages, etc. over a year.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't they? They should. They should also pay the payroll taxes on your earnings. This, assuming you're physically in the US.

Since you're physically present in the US and are a US resident, your employer has nexus in the State you're resident of. Your employer is required to register as a foreign entity and pay all the payroll taxes an employer in your State is required to pay. Also, they should issue you W2, and withhold the applicable amounts on your behalf, as also they should pay the FICA taxes.

Be careful when you tell them that, you may end up being fired.

If you're not an employee, but rather a contractor - then they don't need to do any of this, and you write down your earnings on Schedule C and pay the self-employment tax.

If you're physically present in the UK, then you report your wages on line 7 of 1040, and you're not subject to FICA on them. Attach a statement that you're paid by a local employer in the foreign country and whatever equivalent to W2 they have in the UK.

Comment: the equivalent of a W2 in the UK is a [P60](https://www.gov.uk/payroll-annual-reporting/give-employees-p60-form)